# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

This is the php code, where it perform phpexcel when it is being uploaded

```
if($model =="R2"){      
        for($j=8;$j<$avail_row;$j++)
        {   
            $content[$data[0]][$counter_2] = "JCY"; 
            $content[$data[2]][$counter_2] = "Penang"; 
            $content[$data[3]][$counter_2] = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1,$j)->getCalculatedValue(); 
            $content[$data[4]][$counter_2] = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2,$j)->getCalculatedValue(); 
            $content[$data[5]][$counter_2] = $model;
            $content[$data[6]][$counter_2] = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(3,$j)->getCalculatedValue(); 
            $cmd = substr($content[$data[6]][$counter_2],0,1);
            if($cmd =='Y')
            {
                $content[$data[1]][$counter_2] = 'AFA';
            }
            else
            {
                $content[$data[1]][$counter_2] = 'APFA';
            }
            $date = PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::toFormattedString($objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(4,$j)->getCalculatedValue(), 'yyyy-mm-dd');
            $time = PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::toFormattedString($objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(5,$j)->getCalculatedValue(), 'hh:mm:ss');
            $combine = $date.' '.$time;
            $combine_02 = strtotime("$combine");
            $content[$data[7]][$counter_2] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$combine_02);
            //echo $content[$data[7]][$counter_2];
            $content[$data[8]][$counter_2] = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(6,$j)->getCalculatedValue(); //lot
            $content[$data[9]][$counter_2] = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(12,$j)->getCalculatedValue(); //lower coil height
            $content[$data[10]][$counter_2] = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(11,$j)->getCalculatedValue(); //upper coil height
            $content[$data[11]][$counter_2] =''; //armrollH0Front
            $content[$data[12]][$counter_2]=''; //armrollH0Mid
            $content[$data[13]][$counter_2]=$objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(13,$j)->getCalculatedValue(); //armrollH0Rear
            $content[$data[14]][$counter_2]=''; //armrollH1Front
            $content[$data[15]][$counter_2]=''; //armrollH1Mid
            $content[$data[16]][$counter_2]=$objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(14,$j)->getCalculatedValue(); //armrollH1Rear
            $content[$data[17]][$counter_2]='';
            $content[$data[18]][$counter_2]=''; //armrollH2Mid
            $content[$data[19]][$counter_2]=$objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(15,$j)->getCalculatedValue(); //armrollH2Rear
            $content[$data[20]][$counter_2]=''; //armrollH3Front
            $content[$data[21]][$counter_2]=''; //armrollH3Mid
            $content[$data[22]][$counter_2]=$objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(16,$j)->getCalculatedValue(); //armrollH3Rear
            $content[$data[23]][$counter_2]=''; //armrollH4Front
            $content[$data[24]][$counter_2]=''; //armrollH4Mid
            $content[$data[25]][$counter_2]=$objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(17,$j)->getCalculatedValue(); //armrollH4Rear
            $content[$data[26]][$counter_2]='';  //armrollH5Front
            $content[$data[27]][$counter_2]=''; //armrollH5Mid
            $content[$data[28]][$counter_2]=$objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(18,$j)->getCalculatedValue(); //armrollH5Rear
            $content[$data[29]][$counter_2]=''; //armrollH6Front
            $content[$data[30]][$counter_2]=''; //armrollH6Mid
            $content[$data[31]][$counter_2]=''; //armrollH6Rear
            $content[$data[32]][$counter_2]=''; //armrollH7Front
            $content[$data[33]][$counter_2]=''; //armrollH7Mid
            $content[$data[34]][$counter_2]=''; //armrollH7Rear
            $content[$data[35]][$counter_2]=''; //armrollH8Front
            $content[$data[36]][$counter_2]=''; //armrollH8Mid
            $content[$data[37]][$counter_2]=''; //armrollH8Rear
            $content[$data[38]][$counter_2]=''; //armrollH9Front
            $content[$data[39]][$counter_2]=''; //armrollH9Mid
            $content[$data[40]][$counter_2]=''; //armrollH9Rear
            $content[$data[41]][$counter_2]=''; //armrollH10Front
            $content[$data[42]][$counter_2]=''; //armrollH10Mid
            $content[$data[43]][$counter_2]=''; //armrollH10Rear
            $content[$data[44]][$counter_2]=''; //armrollH11Front
            $content[$data[45]][$counter_2]=''; //armrollH11Mid
            $content[$data[46]][$counter_2]=''; //armrollH11Rear
            $content[$data[47]][$counter_2]=''; //armrollH12Front
            $content[$data[48]][$counter_2]=''; //armrollH12Mid
            $content[$data[49]][$counter_2]=''; //armrollH12Rear
            $content[$data[50]][$counter_2]=''; //armrollH13Front
            $content[$data[51]][$counter_2]=''; //armrollH13Mid
            $content[$data[52]][$counter_2]=''; //armrollH13Rear
            $content[$data[53]][$counter_2]=''; //armrollH14Front
            $content[$data[54]][$counter_2]=''; //armrollH14Mid
            $content[$data[55]][$counter_2]=''; //armrollH14Rear
            $content[$data[56]][$counter_2]=''; //armrollH15Front
            $content[$data[57]][$counter_2]=''; //armrollH15Mid
            $content[$data[58]][$counter_2]=''; //armrollH15Rear
            $content[$data[59]][$counter_2]=''; //armrollH16Front
            $content[$data[60]][$counter_2]=''; //armrollH16Mid
            $content[$data[61]][$counter_2]=''; //armrollH16Rear
            $content[$data[62]][$counter_2]=''; //armrollH17Front
            $content[$data[63]][$counter_2]=''; //armrollH17Mid
            $content[$data[64]][$counter_2]=''; //armrollH17Rear
            $content[$data[65]][$counter_2] =''; //minpivottorque
            $content[$data[66]][$counter_2] =''; //averagepivottorque
            $content[$data[67]][$counter_2] =''; //peakpivottorque
            $content[$data[68]][$counter_2] =''; //pivotparallelism
            $content[$data[69]][$counter_2] =''; //flextodatumd
            $content[$data[70]][$counter_2] =''; //ubendstiffener
            $content[$data[71]][$counter_2] =''; //tring
            $content[$data[72]][$counter_2] ='Y'; //OQA
            $content[$data[74]][$counter_2] =''; //armrollheadbottomfront
            $content[$data[75]][$counter_2] =''; //armrollBottomMid
            $content[$data[76]][$counter_2] =''; //armrollheadbottomrear
            $content[$data[77]][$counter_2] =''; //armrollheadtopfront
            $content[$data[78]][$counter_2] =''; 
            $content[$data[79]][$counter_2] =''; //armrollheadtoprear
            $content[$data[80]][$counter_2] = '';
            //81=>'pnta1',
            $content[$data[81]][$counter_2] ='';
            //82=>'pnta2',
            $content[$data[82]][$counter_2] ='';
            //83=>'pnta3',
            $content[$data[83]][$counter_2] ='';
            //84=>'pnta4',
            $content[$data[84]][$counter_2] ='';
            //85=>'pnta5',
            $content[$data[85]][$counter_2] ='';
            //86=>'pnta6',
            $content[$data[86]][$counter_2] ='';
            //87=>'pnta7',
            $content[$data[87]][$counter_2] ='';
            //88=>'pnta8',
            $content[$data[88]][$counter_2] ='';
            //89=>'pnta9',
            $content[$data[89]][$counter_2] ='';
            //90=>'pnta10',
            $content[$data[90]][$counter_2] ='';
            //91=>'pnta11',
            $content[$data[91]][$counter_2] ='';
            //92=>'pnta12',
            $content[$data[92]][$counter_2] ='';
            //93=>'pnta13',
            $content[$data[93]][$counter_2] ='';
            //94=>'pnta14',
            $content[$data[94]][$counter_2] ='';
            //95=>'pnta15',
            $content[$data[95]][$counter_2] ='';
            //96=>'pnta16',
            $content[$data[96]][$counter_2] ='';
            //97=>'pntb1',
            $content[$data[97]][$counter_2] ='';
            //98=>'pntb2',
            $content[$data[98]][$counter_2] ='';
            //99=>'pntb3',
            $content[$data[99]][$counter_2] ='';
            //100=>'pntb4',
            $content[$data[100]][$counter_2] ='';
            //101=>'pntb5',
            $content[$data[101]][$counter_2] ='';
            //102=>'pntb6',
            $content[$data[102]][$counter_2] ='';
            //103=>'pntb7',
            $content[$data[103]][$counter_2] ='';
            //104=>'pntb8',
            $content[$data[104]][$counter_2] ='';
            //105=>'pntb9',
            $content[$data[105]][$counter_2] ='';
            //106=>'pntb10',
            $content[$data[106]][$counter_2] ='';
            //107=>'pntb11',
            $content[$data[107]][$counter_2] ='';
            //108=>'pntb12',
            $content[$data[108]][$counter_2] ='';
            //109=>'pntb13',
            $content[$data[109]][$counter_2] ='';
            //110=>'pntb14',
            $content[$data[110]][$counter_2] ='';
            //111=>'pntb15',
            $content[$data[111]][$counter_2] ='';
            //112=>'pntb16',
            $content[$data[112]][$counter_2] ='';
            //113=>'armp1',
            $content[$data[113]][$counter_2] ='';
            //114=>'armp2',
            $content[$data[114]][$counter_2] ='';
            //115=>'armp3',
            $content[$data[115]][$counter_2] ='';
            //116=>'armp4',
            $content[$data[116]][$counter_2] ='';
            //117=>'armp5',
            $content[$data[117]][$counter_2] ='';
            //118=>'armp6',
            $content[$data[118]][$counter_2] ='';
            //119=>'armp7',
            $content[$data[119]][$counter_2] ='';
            //120=>'armp8',
            $content[$data[120]][$counter_2] ='';
            //121=>'armp9',
            $content[$data[121]][$counter_2] ='';
            //122=>'armp10',
            $content[$data[122]][$counter_2] ='';
            //122=>'armp10',
            $content[$data[123]][$counter_2] ='';
            //123=>'armp11',
            $content[$data[124]][$counter_2] ='';
            //124=>'armp12',
            $content[$data[125]][$counter_2] ='';
            //125=>'armp13',
            $content[$data[126]][$counter_2] ='';
            //126=>'armp14',
            $content[$data[127]][$counter_2] ='';
            //128=>'armp16',
            $content[$data[128]][$counter_2] ='';
            //129=>'starttorque',
            $content[$data[129]][$counter_2] ='';
            //130=>'torque45',
            $content[$data[130]][$counter_2] =''; //P-P Torque 45
            //131=>'torque360'
            $content[$data[131]][$counter_2] =''; //P-P Torque 360
            $content[$data[132]][$counter_2]=$objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(19,$j)->getCalculatedValue();//Arm Height Center Line Point a H1

            $content[$data[133]][$counter_2]=$objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(20,$j)->getCalculatedValue(); //Arm Height Center Line Point a H2

            $content[$data[134]][$counter_2]=$objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(21,$j)->getCalculatedValue(); //Arm Height Center Line Point a H3

            $content[$data[135]][$counter_2]=$objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(22,$j)->getCalculatedValue(); //Arm Height Center Line Point a H4


            $counter_2++;
        }
    }
```

Mysql query goes here,

```
if($model == "R2"){
            //72, 73
            //73 => 'N'

            $strSQL_0 = "INSERT INTO overall_data(".$data[0].", ".$data[1].", ".$data[2].", ".$data[3].", ".$data[4].", ".$data[5].",
                ".$data[6].", ".$data[7].", ".$data[8].", ".$data[9].", ".$data[10].", ".$data[13].", ".$data[16].", ".$data[19].",
                ".$data[22].", ".$data[25].", ".$data[28].", ".$data[66].", ".$data[67].", ".$data[68].", ".$data[72].", ".$data[73].", ".$data[131].", ".$data[132]."., ".$data[133]."., ".$data[134]."., ".$data[135].")  
            VALUES('". ${$data[0]} ."', '". ${$data[1]} ."', '". ${$data[2]} ."', '". ${$data[3]} ."', '". ${$data[4]} ."', 
                '". ${$data[5]} ."', '". ${$data[6]} ."', '". ${$data[7]} ."', '". ${$data[8]} ."', '". ${$data[9]} ."', 
                '". ${$data[10]} ."', '". ${$data[13]} ."', '". ${$data[16]} ."', '". ${$data[19]} ."', '". ${$data[22]} ."', '". ${$data[25]} ."', '". ${$data[28]} ."', '". ${$data[66]} ."', '". ${$data[67]} ."', '". ${$data[68]} ."', '". ${$data[72]} ."', 'N', '". ${$data[131]} ."', '". ${$data[132]} ."', '". ${$data[133]} ."', '". ${$data[134]} ."', '". ${$data[135]} ."')";

            //echo "<br/>SQL: ".$strSQL_0."<br/>";
            $ins_dataz = mysql_query ($strSQL_0,$link) or die ( "Sql error R2 : sql: ".$strSQL_0." <br/>error:".mysql_error());
            //here

        }
```

I did try check and all my data are correct,but it still showing this error:

> Sql error R2 : sql: INSERT INTO overall_data(supplier_name, commodity, supplier_site, WD_part_number, barcode, prod_codes, trayno, datetimez, lotno, lowercoilheight, uppercoilheight, armrollH0Rear, armrollH1Rear, armrollH2Rear, armrollH3Rear, armrollH4Rear, armrollH5Rear, averagepivottorque, peakpivottorque, pivotparallelism, OQA, exp_sts, torque360, armhtctlineA_h1., armhtctlineA_h2., armhtctlineA_h3., armhtctlineA_h4) VALUES('JCY', 'AFA', 'Penang', '2053800250B07', '7CG1FA11DD0R2', 'R2', 'YCG12053800250B07BE02M0', '2019-07-10 12:58:43', '02-0776', '5.1793', '7.3747', '0.03', '0.036', '0.051', '0.097', '0.045', '0.097', '', '', '', 'Y', 'N', '', '', '', '', '') 
>   error:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' armhtctlineA_h2., armhtctlineA_h3., armhtctlineA_h4)  VALUES('JCY', 'AFA',' at line 3

Comment: Remove the dots from your query.

Comment: Thanks for the response, which dots are you referring to ?

Comment: Please read the error you're getting and you'll find it

Comment: `armhtctlineA_h1., armhtctlineA_h2., armhtctlineA_h3.,`

Comment: Also, wouldn't it be easier if you created a foreach loop to add all values to your query?

Comment: Thanks all for the help ,managed to make it right !

Answer (score -2):

Your Query shoud like this.

```
if($model == "R2"){
        //72, 73
        //73 => 'N'

        $strSQL_0 = "INSERT INTO overall_data(".$data[0].", ".$data[1].", ".$data[2].", ".$data[3].", ".$data[4].", ".$data[5].", ".$data[6].", ".$data[7].", ".$data[8].", ".$data[9].", ".$data[10].", ".$data[13].",".$data[16].", ".$data[19].",".$data[22].", ".$data[25].", ".$data[28].", ".$data[66].", ".$data[67].", ".$data[68].", ".$data[72].", ".$data[73].", ".$data[131].", ".$data[132].", ".$data[133].", ".$data[134].",  ".$data[135].") VALUES('". ${$data[0]} ."', '". ${$data[1]} ."', '". ${$data[2]} ."', '". ${$data[3]} ."', '". ${$data[4]} ."', '". ${$data[5]} ."', '". ${$data[6]} ."', '". ${$data[7]} ."', '". ${$data[8]} ."', '". ${$data[9]} ."', '". ${$data[10]} ."', '". ${$data[13]} ."', '". ${$data[16]} ."', '". ${$data[19]} ."', '". ${$data[22]} ."', '". ${$data[25]} ."', '". ${$data[28]} ."', '". ${$data[66]} ."', '". ${$data[67]} ."', '". ${$data[68]} ."', '". ${$data[72]} ."', 'N', '". ${$data[131]} ."', '". ${$data[132]} ."', '". ${$data[133]} ."', '". ${$data[134]} ."', '". ${$data[135]} ."')";

        //echo "<br/>SQL: ".$strSQL_0."<br/>";
        $ins_dataz = mysql_query ($strSQL_0,$link) or die ( "Sql error R2 : sql: ".$strSQL_0." <br/>error:".mysql_error());
        //here

}
```

Or if you want to prevent-sql-injection.

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
set_exception_handler(function($e) {
  error_log($e->getMessage());
  exit('Error connecting to database'); //Should be a message a typical user could understand
});
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "databaseName");
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8mb4");


$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO myTable (".$data[0].", ".$data[1].", ".$data[2].", ".$data[3].", ".$data[4].", ".$data[5].", ".$data[6].", ".$data[7].", ".$data[8].", ".$data[9].", ".$data[10].", ".$data[13].",".$data[16].", ".$data[19].",".$data[22].", ".$data[25].", ".$data[28].", ".$data[66].", ".$data[67].", ".$data[68].", ".$data[72].", ".$data[73].", ".$data[131].", ".$data[132].", ".$data[133].", ".$data[134].",  ".$data[135].") VALUES (? ,? ,? ,? ,? ,? ,? ,? ,? ,? ,? ,? ,? ,? ,? ,? ,? ,? ,? ,? ,? ,? ,? ,? ,? ,? ,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("si", ${$data[0]} , ${$data[1]} , ${$data[2]} , ${$data[3]} , ${$data[4]} , ${$data[5]} , ${$data[6]} , ${$data[7]} , ${$data[8]} , ${$data[9]} , ${$data[10]} , ${$data[13]} , ${$data[16]} , ${$data[19]} , ${$data[22]} , ${$data[25]} , ${$data[28]} , ${$data[66]} , ${$data[67]} , ${$data[68]} , ${$data[72]} , 'N', ${$data[131]} , ${$data[132]} , ${$data[133]} , ${$data[134]} , ${$data[135]});
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: SQL injections, *ahoy*!

Comment: @esqew see this is a sipmple solution of issue, it's not my job to tell additional things like **SQL injections**.